# Replacing Reporting Services with JavaScript Solution using DataTables

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

We are getting rid of Reporting services due to its pitiful performance, and I am looking at using http://www.datatables.net/index to provide the functionality of paging through the results and such.

Performance is critical, so I only what to pull back ( AJAX ) the data needed for the page of records the user is currently viewing.

There are other plug ins available too that are similar, and I am sure that I am not the first to have this requirement.  Anyone done something similar, and if so I would love to hear how you solved this problem ( high level of course ).

Are there any other plugins better equipped to provide the functionality I outlined above?  ( Pulling back a page worth of data at a time via ajax )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid is the answer.  Very simple to use, and does the job without the overhead of SSRS.  I realized today when looking at my profile, that I had an unanswered question that I, well, answered.

:-)